# intellij doesn't recognize jvm when I try to configure jdk

Tags: intellij-idea, jvm

I'm working on mint-cinnamon as my file-system and running intellij on it,
I'm trying to add jdk to intellij but when i'm looking for it trough intellij it doesn't show any jdk nor jvm file though I know that these files exist (open jdk 8 and open jdk 11 and jvm) and I  know where they are.

I've tried reinstall jdk11 and 8, rebuild the project, and download lib32.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBDIb.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqzrQ.png),     [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBNSQ.png)

Comment: You need the complete JDK installation with the standard directories structure (jre,lib,bin subdirectories).

Answer (score 0):

try: Project structure -> Platform settings -> SDKs

Then add the path to the jdk.

After that got to Project under Project settings and select the project SDK.

I've worked with mint and intellij, and had no problems.